# GM_setClipboard (and other GM functions) gives an error in a Firefox but not Chrome/Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm working in Firefox and trying to create a function that will copy a link's text when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>* (Numpad)</kbd>.

The code works in Chrome Tampermonkey usually, but for some reason it's doing nothing in Firefox.
The following error is reported in the console:

> "ReferenceError: GM_setClipboard is not defined"

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener( "keydown", function(i) {
    var selectLink = $('a').eq(8); // The link by index
    var targetLink = selectLink.text(); // The link text

    if (i.keyCode === 106 && i.shiftKey) // Shift+Num*
    {
        GM_setClipboard(targetLink); // Copy to clipboard
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any error message or something like that? What is the actual and the expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes, sorry I just figured out how to retrieve the error messages from Greasemonkey in console, The error is "ReferenceError: GM_setClipboard is not defined". The expected behavior is that when I press Shift+* it will copy the text of the selected link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Greasemonkey requires explicit `@grant` statements](http://www.greasespot.net/2014/06/sandbox-api-changes-in-greasemonkey-20.html) to use `GM_` functions.  Whereas Tampermonkey still does some auto detection (a potential security hole).

So:

1. You need to specify `// @grant GM_setClipboard` in your [metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block).
2. However, this switches the sandbox back on (a good thing), so you also need to make sure you've `@require`d jQuery.

This script will work in both Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @match    http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM.setClipboard
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener ( "keydown", function (i) {
    var selectLink = $('a').eq (8); // The link by index
    var targetLink = selectLink.text ().trim (); // The link text

    if (i.keyCode === 106  &&  i.shiftKey) // Shift+Num*
    {
        GM.setClipboard (targetLink); // Copy to clipboard
    }
} );
```

Comment: Its `GM.setClipboard` now (`.` not `_`). `@grant` is still required and must also be corrected. Tested in Firefox 68.3 (from december 2019) with Grease Monkey 4.9.